# How can I prepare a string for parse

Tags: javascript, json

I need to parse

```
'[{"message":"Argument \"absoluteDateTimeFilter\" has invalid value {startDate: \"2021-03-01\", endDate: \"2021-03-09\", groupingLevel: undefined}.\nIn field \"groupingLevel\": Expected type \"PeriodLevelId\", found undefined.","locations":[{"line":1,"column":70}]}]'
```

- String type

into two key-value pairs - the 'message' and the 'location'. But I get SyntaxError which references to `\"absoluteDateTimeFilter\"`

***What i tried***

When I hardcoded spaces instead of `\"` and `\"` it still getting an error but now it is linking to `.\n`

Is there a flexible solution to this problem?

Thanks you!

Comment: you ca directly assign these to any variable with single quote like below : 
let response = [{"message":"Argument \"absoluteDateTimeFilter\" has invalid value {startDate: \"2021-03-01\", endDate: \"2021-03-09\", groupingLevel: undefined}.\nIn field \"groupingLevel\": Expected type \"PeriodLevelId\", found undefined.","locations":[{"line":1,"column":70}]}]

Answer (score -1):

You can try this. It will work for you.

```js
const data = [{"message":"Argument \"absoluteDateTimeFilter\" has invalid value {startDate: \"2021-03-01\", endDate: \"2021-03-09\", groupingLevel: undefined}.\nIn field \"groupingLevel\": Expected type \"PeriodLevelId\", found undefined.","locations":[{"line":1,"column":70}]}];

let stringfyData=JSON.stringify(data);
let strReplaced = stringfyData.replaceAll(String.fromCharCode(92,34), "'");
 let parseArray=JSON.parse(strReplaced);
 console.log("Message::",parseArray[0].message);
console.log("locations::", parseArray[0].locations);
```